# Which XCode version supports on Mac osx Leopard 10.5.2?

Tags: xcode, macos, ios

After the efforts of three months I am able to install mac osx Leopard on my non apple laptop. But with my bad luck I got older version 10.5.2.

Can any one please tell me which version of `iOS` and `XCode` is supported for my mac version.
From where to get it because I can't get older version of `XCode` on Apple's site

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can anybody tell me why -1 on a question which was asked more than a year ago??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Folks,
I am not succeed for getting ios supported on Leopard 10.5.2. May be I am wrong and want to be.. but after a lot of googling and download 4 different ios I share my experience here for other mates if they have same issue...

I don't know about ios 2.0, 2.1, 2.2 but these are based on device only as much I know.

The ios 3.0 needs Leopard 10.5.3 at least.
i0s 3.1.2 needs 10.5.7. So don't waste time to find ios for 10.5.2 and try to find Mac Leopard 10.5.7 or latest

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

XCode 3.1.4 installs on OS 10.5.0 and can be downloaded from https://developer.apple.com.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version will suite your request, but to get older versions of XCode just visit to http://connect.apple.com/ and check the Developer Tools on the right sidebar.
You need the free ADC membership to access it.
Good luck.

Comment: I got a download link for xcode 3.1.3 & 3.1.4 supported on my mac version...Can you please tell me that does it contain iphone sdk too..or I have to download it from somewhere else...And if then which version to download

Comment: Sorry I have to ask Which version of ios is supported on Leopard 10.5.2? Can you give me the download link?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't actually know this. I guess you should go through the system minimum requirements of each XCode version and see what's written in the release notes.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using Kalyway or something similar.  Check out this article...

http://www.brucebarrera.com/?p=265

You can update the config file to say you are whatever version you want.  I might try to fake a snow leopard version on my leopard install...

Answer (score 0):

You can install Mac OS 10.8.2 also on your non apple laptop. Xcode 4 can be installed then.

Comment: thanks for your answer but this question is almost 4 year older.